# Передать данные из js в php без кнопки

Tags: javascript, php, html

форма html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form name="form" action="" method="get">
      <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" value="Car Loan">
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

php

```
 <?php echo $_GET['subject']; ?>
```

Есть форма, она передает данные только когда нажал enter, как сделать так что бы он передавал данные не по нажатию кнопки enter, а сразу когда их ввел?

Я еще сделал по другому:

```
<form name="form" action="" method="get">
<input type="text" name="subject" id="input" value="Car Loan"><span id="result"></span>
</form>
<script>
  input.oninput = function() {
    result.innerHTML = input.value;
  };
</script>

<h1>
<?php echo $_GET['subject']; ?>
</h1>
```

я сделал вот так, но в php данные не передаются

Comment: `document.getElementById("subject").oninput  = function () { this.closest("form").submit(); };`

Comment: С помощью jquery например, как только убирается фокус с поля ввода, поле обрабатывается скриптом. Смотрите документацию [Focusout](https://api.jquery.com/focusout/)

Comment: Если фокус не будет убран, данные не отправятся на сервер.

Comment: В вашем же скрипте получается при каждой задержке пользователя в строке ввода, происходит повторное отправление данных. 
И что тогда будет если после ввода идет отправка данных в бд или на почту?

Comment: Не совсем. Debounce работает по принципу, пока ты вызываешь событие input чаще чем 1 раз в 500 мс, данные не будут отправляться на сервер. И результат будет такой, если пользователь прекратил печатать данные уйдут на сервер

Comment: Это я и имел ввиду, человек при вводе данных может отвлекаться и во время этого происходит отправка данных на сервер

Comment: Читайте внимательнее вопрос. "... а сразу когда их ввел"

Comment: пример: ввожу свой емейл в поле... email@... разговариваю с сотрудником....оп, а форма уже отправилась

Comment: Конечно если форма принимает емейл или телефон, то вполне ваш вариант идеально подойдет, дописав в скрипт проверку корректного ввода, после прописанных 500мс. Если прошел проверку данные улетели.

Comment: мне такой вариант не подходит

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Лучше всего добавить задержку перед отправкой. К примеру [debounce](https://lodash.com/docs/#debounce)

```js
function debounce(fn, delay) {
  let t = 0
  return function (...args) {
    clearTimeout(t)
    t = window.setTimeout(() => fn.apply(this, args), delay)
  }
}

function sendValue() {
  console.log(this.value) 
}

const subject = document.getElementById('subject')

if (subject) {
  subject.addEventListener('input', debounce(sendValue, 500))
}
```

```html
<form id="form1" name="form" action="" method="get">
  <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" value="Car Loan">
</form>
```